# How to vary the selection from the distribution of a continuous colour sequence?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to create a function that takes a dataframe and then creates and shows a Plotly figure.

I've got as far as this:

```
import datetime as dt

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "cat": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"] * 2,
            "date": [dt.date(2020, 1, 1)] * 10 + [dt.date(2020, 1, 2)] * 10,
            "count": list(range(1, 11)) + list(range(11, 21)),
        },
    )

    show_fig(df)

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "cat": ["A", "B", "C"] * 2,
            "date": [dt.date(2020, 1, 1)] * 3 + [dt.date(2020, 1, 2)] * 3,
            "count": list(range(1, 4)) + list(range(4, 7)),
        },
    )

    show_fig(df)


def show_fig(df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    fig = px.bar(
        data_frame=df,
        x="date",
        y="count",
        color="cat",
        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Viridis,
    )

    fig.update_xaxes(dtick="D1")

    fig.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which works fine but my issue is that the number of `cat` values is variable and could be between 1 and 10.

This means the first plot looks great when there are 10 `cat` values:

[image]

The colours are nicely distributed.

However, there isn't enough separation in colours in the second plot:

[image]

I understand I'm using a sequential colour sequence instead of a discrete sequence but the standard discrete sequences aren't great.

I guess I could create custom colour sequences for 1, 2, 3 etc discrete `cat` values. So creating a `Viridis` based sequence for 5 `cat` values might look something like this:

```
[
    "#440154",
    # "#482878",
    "#3e4989",
    # "#31688e",
    "#26828e",
    # "#1f9e89",
    "#35b779",
    # "#6ece58",
    "#b5de2b",
    # "#fde725",
]
```

Which would result in a plot with more distributed colours:

[image]

However, I'm wondering if there's a better and more scalable way of working with colour sequences? Indeed if the dataframe suddenly has 10+ `cat` values then the colours will start repeating which I'd want to avoid.

How could I build a scalable function?